# c3.js TypeError: b.value is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, c3.js

I am trying to make a graph using a JSON object created in my PHP. I keep getting **TypeError: b.value is undefined** in the JS log but my data seems to be in the same format as the example in their documentation.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
  $da=date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-'. $i .' days'));
  $a=mt_rand(150,200);
  $b=mt_rand(100,150);
  $ar["date"][]=$da;
  $ar["Score"][]=$a;
  $ar["ScoreB"][]=$b;

}  
 $all=json_encode($ar);      

 <script>
    var arr=<?php echo $all; ?>;
    var chart = c3.generate({
         bindto: '#scoring',
        data: {
            json: arr,
            type: 'spline',
            keys:{
                x:'date'
            }
        },
        color: {
            pattern: ['red', 'orange']
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    format: '%Y-%m-%d'
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The Object is

```
{"date":"2016-05-09","2016-05-08","2016-05-07","2016-05-06","2016-05-05","2016-05-04","2016-05-03","2016-05-02","2016-05-01","2016-04-30"],"Score":[182,163,196,153,180,154,170,177,191,173],"ScoreB":[121,149,138,113,104,107,111,109,119,132]}
```

I also ran it with the object in the format of

```
[{"date":"2016-05-09","Score":191,"ScoreB":119},{"date":"2016-05-08","Score":166,"ScoreB":140},{"date":"2016-05-07","Score":172,"ScoreB":103},{"date":"2016-05-06","Score":187,"ScoreB":139},{"date":"2016-05-05","Score":162,"ScoreB":100},{"date":"2016-05-04","Score":197,"ScoreB":121},{"date":"2016-05-03","Score":167,"ScoreB":145},{"date":"2016-05-02","Score":160,"ScoreB":137},{"date":"2016-05-01","Score":175,"ScoreB":100},{"date":"2016-04-30","Score":156,"ScoreB":127}]
```

And I still have the same error.

I have been stuck on this for a day and it seems like it should be easy but I can not figure it out. If I put the same data in the format of "columns" it works but going forward I need this JSON to work.

Comment: That object looks wrong. Did you type or cut-and-paste it?

Comment: I copy-pasted it so that's exactly what it is.

Comment: I also added the second format of the object I tried and i still have the same error in the JS console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me when cut'n'pasted into http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html , see the change in the keys section with the added *value* field - http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-keys

The only difference is that I changed the binding ID to work in the c3 examples page, and I used the json directly, not php generated.

```
var arr = [{"date":"2016-05-09","Score":191,"ScoreB":119},{"date":"2016-05-08","Score":166,"ScoreB":140},{"date":"2016-05-07","Score":172,"ScoreB":103},{"date":"2016-05-06","Score":187,"ScoreB":139},{"date":"2016-05-05","Score":162,"ScoreB":100},{"date":"2016-05-04","Score":197,"ScoreB":121},{"date":"2016-05-03","Score":167,"ScoreB":145},{"date":"2016-05-02","Score":160,"ScoreB":137},{"date":"2016-05-01","Score":175,"ScoreB":100},{"date":"2016-04-30","Score":156,"ScoreB":127}]; ;

var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
        data: {
            json: arr,
            type: 'spline',
            keys:{
                x:'date',
                value: ['Score', 'ScoreB'], // IMPORTANT
            }
        },
        color: {
            pattern: ['red', 'orange']
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    format: '%Y-%m-%d'
                }
            }
        }
    });
```